# How to create an .ipa file with a prebuilt binary?

Tags: ios, rust

I have created an executable binary file outside of XCode via the Rust compiler, but I do not have any clue how to create the .ipa file.

If it is possible, I would also like to debug that binary via XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's tooling for App Store is going to be a pain to reproduce outside Xcode.

To use Rust in App Store programs it's best to make a minimal regular C/ObjC Xcode project, and add Rust code to it via a static library.

1. Add `crate-type = ["staticlib"]` to Cargo.toml
2. Add external build system to your Xcode project, make it run cargo
3. Add static library produced by Cargo to libraries linked in your project
4. Add `#[no_mangle] extern fn` functions to your code to be able to call them from C.
5. Use cbindgen or create header file manually for your functions from Rust
6. Call them.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gifski-app is an example that does this.

Comment: I knew that, and currently using it in my project https://github.com/Hossein-Noroozpour/vulkust but this could be a great help in my project design, because I don't like to do much in outside of Rust (for example, I have written a pure Rust Android Glue in my project) and finally I believe that there is a hacking way around this problem, but I'm not very familiar with Apple technologies.